# Is it possible to make an image centerInside with a blurred background with glide library?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide, image-scaling

I am familiar with fitcenter and centercrop in glide. But is it possible to make something like this image

[image]

Any ideas to achieve it?

Comment: I think they are 2 different imageviews, stacked one on top of other. The bottom one loads an blurred/thumb version of the main image which is displayed in high resolution on the top imageview

Comment: ya we can achieve it like that. But 2 ImageViews are needed.

Answer (score 5):

Use two imageViews. One smaller and above the other. Then use this [library](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) and use this piece of code for the background image

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.demo)
  .apply(bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(25)))
  .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
```